# Entity Framework VS2013 VB Error Add SP

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Hi I have the following problem, use entity framework with VS2013 in my project, all was well, and now when I try to add a stored procedure to the model not shown me, not get error but the procedure is not loaded. I appreciate any help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedures are not visible in the designer window.

Look in the Model Browser in the .Store to find them.

- Look in .Store (in Model Broswer)
- There will be a corresponding Function Import in the EF Model (in Model Browser)
- That is where the definition of your function is.
- You can call your stored procedure using that Function Import definition.

Comment: Thank for your answer
It is in the Model Explorer (Model Browser) where the SP does not appear, nor as function either as a stored procedure, not get error only not adds it after "update model from database" and select SP.
The only recent change was to switch to a new computer where you install again the SQL and VS2013, just like my previous computer. but any time I get error, just not add it.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there an error message (pop up, console, output)?

Comment: Can you import and use tables no problem?

Comment: not in the console does not leave any error, the same happens to me to try to add a table or a view.